# How to insert two stacked buttons, but in inline form?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal that contains two multiple select and two buttons. I would like to have all controls inline, but the two buttons stacked, example:

```
         BUTTON
SELECT           SELECT
         BUTTON
```

I have the following. The form is displayed inline, but the buttons are not stacked (but rather next to each other).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="modal-body">

  <div style="display:inline">
    <select id="fam" name="fam" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" size="8" style="width: 300px">
            </select>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 2</button>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline">
    <select id="fam_" name="fam" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" size="8" style="width: 300px">
    
            </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Move the buttons into separate `div`s inside that inline `div`. Maybe that could work.

Comment: That actually worked, haven't thought of that! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap supports vertically stacked buttons with btn-group-vertical. Sounds like that's exactly what you want plus it merges the borders of the buttons together to make them look nice.

Here's an example from the w3 schools documentation:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_button_group_v&stacked=h

That would replace your middle div, between the selects